# RSpec test for ActiveAdmin member_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, activeadmin

I've got custom member_action in my Active Admin panel which is responsible for resending devise reset password instructions.

`admin/users.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  member_action :reset_password do
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    user.send_reset_password_instructions
    redirect_to(admin_user_path(user),
                notice: "Password reset email sent to #{user.email}")
  end
end
```

How to write RSpec tests for such an action? The only thing I found is [this one](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/5371) and I think it's not quite related to my problem.

I was trying to sth like below:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Admin::UsersController, type: :controller do
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  let!(:admin) { create(:admin_user) }

  before(:each) do
    sign_in admin
  end

  describe 'GET user' do
    let(:user) { create(:user, :random_email) }

    before(:each) do
      User.should_receive(:find).at_least(:once).and_return(user)
      get :show
    end

    it 'sends email' do
      get :reset_password
      expect(user).should_receive(:send_reset_password_instructions)
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"reset_password", :controller=>"admin/users"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it turns out small adjustments (pass the user.id in params) make the trick.

```
describe Admin::UsersController, type: :controller do
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

  before { sign_in admin }

  let!(:admin) { create(:admin_user) }

  describe 'GET user' do
    let(:user) { create(:user, :random_email) }

    before do
      allow(User).to receive(:find).at_least(:once) { user }
      get :show, params: { id: user.id }
    end

    it 'sends email' do
      get :reset_password, params: { id: user.id }
      expect(flash[:notice]).to match("Password reset email sent to #{user.email}")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to use a feature test, since when using active admin, UI stuff handle by the framework:

```rb
RSpec.feature 'Reset Password', type: :feature do
  let(:user) { create :user }
  
  before do
    login_as(user, scope: :user)
  end

  scenario 'can delete future episode' do
    visit some_path
    click_link 'Reset Password'
    expect(page.current_path).to eq(admin_user_path(user))
    expect(page).to have_content("Password reset email sent to #{user.email}")
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'create' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ResetPassword:0x00007fe426207dc8>`

Comment: Have you load factory bot methods?  ``` config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods```

Comment: In `rails_helper` - yes I did

Comment: Would you like to replace using FactotyBot.create instead create? Just see if it works.

Comment: Nope `NameError: uninitialized constant FactotyBot`

Comment: sorry for typo, it should FactoryBot.create

Comment: After this change I'm getting new error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'login_as' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ResetPassword:0x00007f97f8850920>`